# Angular 6 - HttpInterceptors - HttpResponse body not getting modified

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm just implementing `HttpInterceptor`, where i would like to `base64` encode the request body and `base64` decode the response body.

- Method : HTTP Post Request / Response
- data format : json (this should
  be encoded / decoded)

Here is the code that i have done. When i debug it, the decoded data (i.e) json is being set back into `event.body`. but, it is not getting received in the services, that actually makes the http call

```
@Injectable()
export class Base64Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private base64UtilService: Base64UtilService) {

    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let requestClone = request.clone(
            {
                body: this.base64UtilService.encode(JSON.stringify(request.body)),
                responseType: 'text'
            }
        )
        return next.handle(requestClone).pipe(tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                debugger;
                let decodedData = this.base64UtilService.decode(event.body);
                event = event.clone({
                    body: decodedData
                });
                return event;
            }
        },
            (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }))
    }

}
```

I'm just getting the same response that actually comes from the server, the decoding of the `event.body` is not reflecting. Thanks for the time

This is how the http call is made

```
 sendActivationRequest(url: string, request: MyRequest): Observable<MyResponse> {
        return this.httpClient.post<MyResponse>(url, request)
          .pipe(map((response: MyResponse) => {
            return response;
          }), catchError((error) => {
            return throwError(error);
          }));
      }
```

Comment: Please post your `http` call method.

Comment: @hrdkisback I have added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained a modified response body successfully by using **map** instead of **tap**:

```
return next.handle(requestClone).pipe(map(event => {...}));
```

It's because of the behaviour of map vs. tap:

From the [tap documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/function/index.html#static-function-tap):
"Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source."

From the [map documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map): "Applies a given project function to each value emitted by the source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable."

Comment: Thanks @Cristina, I'll try your solution and come back!